# How to get ID of the referenced resource by a different resource?

Tags: android, android-resources

I would like to get the ID of the referenced resource in runtime. For example this is my code:

```
<string name="d2c_entryroadblock_start_value" translatable="false">@string/get_started</string>
```

and I am interested in the ID of the `R.string.get_started` having only the reference to `R.string.d2c_entryroadblock_start_value` in runtime.

You can also see how it looks in the APK analyzer below - I need to get that `@ref/0x7f1302fc`

[image: APK analyzer screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get that with the `Resources#getValue()` method, passing `false` for the `resolveRefs` parameter. For example:

```
TypedValue value = new TypedValue();
getResources().getValue(R.string.alias_name, value, false);
int aliasedId = value.data;
```

As shown, the numerical ID for the aliased resource will be in the `TypedValue`'s `data` field. If you actually need it in hexadecimal, you can pass it to `Integer.toHexString()`. And, if you need the aliased resource name, then it's simply:

```
String aliasedName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(value.data);
```